# Force Emacs to NOT change the encoding

Tags: emacs, encoding, pasting

I'll try to put this as clearly as possible, since I myself don't understand very well what's going on.

If I have a buffer opened in Emacs, and it's in, let's say UTF-8 (could be anything really), and I paste some text that is in another encoding (from a PDF for example), Emacs will CHANGE the original encoding (UTF8) to the new encoding...

This is a pain in the ass, because it screws up thousands of other text lines, just so the new line can be correctly displayed...

So I guess my question is, how can I tell Emacs to NEVER change the encoding of the file? If a character can't be represented in the present encoding, than just don't show it (or show it all messed up like usually happens).

Thanks

Comment: I think you can choose the encoding for the next operation, yank being one such operation. I think the key for it is... `C-x C-m c`.

Comment: Does this happen if you run emacs with the -Q option (ie, ignore any customizations that you have made).

Comment: The encoding is not changed by the yank.  Emacs does not pay attention to encodings while editing the buffer, but only when reading/writing its content to disk (or sending it to/from another program).  You probably want to report the problem via `M-x report-emacs-bug`, while being careful to provide as much data as possible (e.g. figure out if Emacs emits a message about the change of coding-system, figure out which other coding system was used, or better yet provide a reproducible recipe).

Answer (score 2):

Specifying `-*- coding: utf-8 -*-` (or whatever encoding you want) at the top of the file will force that encoding for that particular file. The relevant manual page is [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specify-Coding.html).

For a more systematic approach, you might want to investigate the docstring for the `file-coding-system-alist` variable, which forces encodings based on filenames.

Comment: Setting file-coding-system-alist to `no-conversion` will save in Emacs's internal encoding.

Comment: Oops, I guess I spoke too soon (should have tested it out first). Edited for correctness.

Comment: @JSON: `no-conversion` does not mean to store in Emacs's encoding.  It is at best a misnomer (there is no such thing as "the absence of conversion").  Just don't use it.  If you want to use Emacs's internal encoding, then use `emacs-internal` (tho it's probably a bad idea to use it anyway).